# Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. in register,js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Good afternoon, I am creating an app in reactjs and all the routes work fine, only the register user gives the error Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a  component.I am using firebase for this, the login with google and user and password works 100%, thanks

register.js code

```
import { push } from "firebase/database";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { Link, Route, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  auth,
  registerWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithGoogle,
} from "../config/firebase";
function Register() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  const register = () => {
    if (!name) alert("Please enter name");
    registerWithEmailAndPassword(name, email, password);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading) return;
    if (user) Route.push("/dashboard");
  }, [user, loading]);
  return (
    <div className="register">
      <div className="register__container">
        <input
          type="text"
          className="register__textBox"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Full Name"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          className="register__textBox"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="E-mail Address"
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          className="register__textBox"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <button className="register__btn" onClick={register}>
          Register
        </button>
        <button
          className="register__btn register__google"
          onClick={signInWithGoogle}
        >
          Register with Google
        </button>
        <div>
          Already have an account? <Link to="/">Login</Link> now.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Register;
```

Comment: You've tagged the question with [tag:next.js], but you're using `react-router-dom` which would indicate otherwise. Is this code from a Next.js app?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap your `React App` within `BrowserRouter` or some router. Go to `index.js` in src folder. Wrap it like this.

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then, add some `Route`. For example, like this.

```
 <BrowserRouter>
       <Routes>
           <Route element={<Home/>} path={"/"} />
           <Route element={<Another />} path={"/another}/>
       </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
```